# WordPress tanslation .po file

Tags: wordpress, translate

I translate one row in a code and still any result.

This row I need translate

[image: This row I need translate]

This is I put into the .po file

[image: This is I put into the .po file]

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I need translate the custom button "Poptávka" on this page usb-4-logo.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

For strings to be translatable you need to use any of WordPress translation functions around the string:

For example:

```
<a href="#">This string</a> <-- this will not be translatable
<a href="#"><?php __e('This string','your-namespace'); ?></a> <-- this will be translatable.
```

You have quite a few methods for making content translatable: `__()`, `_e()` and others. Read more in the documentation about translation: https://codex.wordpress.org/L10n

Comment: Thank you, I try it. And what belongs instead 'your-namespace' ?

Comment: That looks correct. Then you can use for example PoEdit to translate your strings and create correct translation files.